# Laravel Passport CreateFreshApiToken initial login & workflow

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a Vue CLI front end, so I'm trying to use Laravel Passport to handle requests' Authentication.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

I have an `api/login` route that does the following ([*almost* copy and pasted from here](https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876)):

```
public function login(){ 
  if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
    $user = Auth::user(); 
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken; 
    return response()->json(['user' => $user], $this->successStatus);
  } 
  else{ 
    return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
  } 
}
```

After I hit it with an AJAX request, the user is successfully logged in.

But if I do something like this in my Vue action:

```
login({commit, dispatch}, {email, password}){
  axios.post('/api/login', {
    email, password 
  }).then( response => {
    console.log("Check login was successful", response.data);
    commit('setUser', response.data);
    axios.get("/api/user").then(response => {
      console.log("Still logged in:", response);
    });
  });
```

The console says the following:

```
Check login was successful {user: {…}}
GET http://localhost:8080/api/user 401 (Unauthorized)
```

The Laravel docs say that...

> This Passport middleware will attach a laravel_token cookie to your outgoing responses.

What am I doing wrong / how do I access this `laravel_token` for future requests?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing the following.

I was already creating the `accessToken`, and never sent it back. So step 1:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
  $user = Auth::user(); 
  $accessToken =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken; 
  return response()->json(compact('user','accessToken'), $this->successStatus);
}
```

Then in my Axios request:

```
axios.post('/api/login', {
    email, password 
  }).then( response => {
    // Send the auth token every time : )
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + response.data.accessToken;
    commit('setUser', response.data.user);
  });
```